# H2 Database Database to Lower Not Valid Connection Setting (2019)

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm trying to connect to an embedded H2 database with the compatibility mode for PostgreSQL.  I'm using the settings as described in the online documentation:

```
jdbc:h2:~/test.h2.db;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Unsupported connection setting "DATABASE_TO_LOWER"
```

Is this still an experimental setting?  Is there a solution and/or workaround for this error?

H2 Database v.1.4.199 + Java 11.0.2 (Oracle)

Comment: So my application was actually running correctly; I had to upgrade the H2 version in the IDE so the compatibility settings would not throw the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple versions of H2 in your classpath and wrong version is actually used. You can check the complete error message to be sure.

For example, version 1.4.197 throws

> Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unsupported connection setting "DATABASE_TO_LOWER" [90113-197]

A `197` indicates a database version.

1.4.199 accepts your URL properly.

Also note that database path in the URL shouldn't include a file name extension. With `~/test.h2.db` the file `test.h2.db.mv.db` will be actually used.

Comment: Yes, that was a bug in H2 v1.4.197 and after update to v1.4.199 it was fixed. This bug was also mentioned din the release notes.
If you are using Spring Boot you can update `spring-boot-starter-parent` to 2.1.7.RELEASE and it will update transitively the H2 version

Answer (score 0):

Please visit http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html

PR #1776: Improve DATABASE_TO_LOWER handling

Try to update your h2 version from 1.4.199

Warning : By default H2 transforms all names into uppercase (ex: fromIP => FROMIP). This setting will pass everything in lowercase but will not keep the case (ex: fromIP => fromip)

Comment: I used the compatibility settings for PostgreSQL with no issues. http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility